# Intent Abrir FaceBook

Tags: android, intent

Como faço para abrir o facebook em uma determinada página.
Abrir principalmente pelo aplicativo caso não esteja instalado abrir no navegado do celular. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Recomendo dar uma olhada nessa resposta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34564211/open-facebook-page-in-facebook-app-if-installed-on-android, como não tenho ambiente para testar, não consigo dizer se funciona. Lembrando que essas soluções são voláteis e podem quebrar a cada atualização. O mais estável talvez seja abrir a url no browser